# Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Forms: InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm using [official documentation for symfony 2.1](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.x/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) for overriding default FOSUserBundle forms. But when I tried to override form handlers I've got this error:

> InvalidArgumentException: The service definition
>   "test_user.form.handler.registration" does not exist.

Files listing:

```
<?php

// src/Test/UserBundle/Form/Handler/RegistrationFormHandler.php

namespace Test\UserBundle\Form\Handler;

use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler as BaseHandler;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

class RegistrationFormHandler extends BaseHandler
{
    protected function onSuccess(UserInterface $user, $confirmation)
    {
        // logic here...
        parent::onSuccess($user, $confirmation);
    }
}
```

=-=-=-=-=

```
# src/Test/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    test_user.form.handler.registration:
        class: Test\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler
        arguments: ["@fos_user.registration.form", "@request", "@fos_user.user_manager", "@fos_user.mailer", "@fos_user.util.token_generator"]
        scope: request
        public: false
```

=-=-=-=-=

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: dev
    user_class: Test\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            handler: test_user.form.handler.registration
```

P.S. Yes, I have read similar questions, but there is not the same problem that I have.

Comment: The problem was simple. I created my `UnserBundle` manually, so folder named `DependencyInjection` has not been created. This folder contains php files, which load services configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple. I created my `UnserBundle` manually, so folder named `DependencyInjection` has not been created. This folder contains php files, which load services configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the last line in `services.yml`. It says `public: false`, that is, this service is not accessible from the code (see [Advanced Container Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html)). You can do one of two things: change the value of `public` to `true` or remove the line since the default value is `true`.

Comment: No, it works with `public: false`. By the way, I figured it out. Look at the my own answer.